# Guardar los diferentes valores de una columna en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito conocer los diferentes valores de una columna que contiene mi dataframe. Para ello empleo la librería `pandas` concretamente `set()`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
xx = set(df['Name'])
print(xx)
```

El problema es que esto me devuelve el contenido similar a un diccionario, es decir, con llaves.

```
{'valor 1','valor 2','valor 3'}
```

Y yo necesito tener esto es una lista. Algo similar a la siguiente línea:

```
['valor 1','valor 2','valor 3']
```

¿Como se puede hacer? He probado a meterlo en una lista `xx = [set(df['Node name'])]` pero me queda lo siguiente, `[{'valor 1','valor 2','valor 3'}]`, pienso que otra manera sería recorrer fila a fila esa columna e ir añadiéndolo a una lista previamente vacía cada vez que aparece uno nuevo. Pero esto me parece demasiado elaborado y que debe existir algo más sencillo ya que pandas suele simplificar bastante las cosas y evita iterar línea a línea.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que `list(set(df["name"]))` o `df["name"].unique()` te serviría.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jason', 'Amy', 'Tina'], 
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2012], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma', 'Puno'])
df
#              name  year  reports
# Cochice     Jason  2012        4
# Pima        Molly  2012       24
# Santa Cruz   Tina  2013       31
# Maricopa     Jake  2014        2
# Yuma          Amy  2014        3
df["name"].unique()
# array(['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Amy'], dtype=object)
list(set(df["name"]))
# ['Molly', 'Tina', 'Amy', 'Jason']
```